# Save data by MySQL after click a link to an external web

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I want to put a clicks counter on banners on my page so advertisers get an idea of how many visitors arrive via my website.

I've seen that could be done by directing the link to an intermediate page that access MySQL (to save the data in a record BD) using PHP, and then redirected to the advertiser's website, but I wonder if there otherwise somewhat more "elegant" to do so.

Could anyone tell me if it is possible?

I've found an similar example, but this one donwload a file and count the visit (I only want to go to another web)

EXAMPLE HTML

```
<span style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href='files/my_file.zip' id='25' onClick='dc(this.id)' target='_blank'>Download this file</a> </span>
```

EXAMPLE Javascript

```
function dc(id){$.post("process.php",{file_id:id})}
```

EXAMPLE Process.php

```
$file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
```

mysql_query("UPDATE file SET downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE id = " .$file_id);

I tried to adapt this example to my code, like this:

HTML

```
echo '<br><a onClick="sumar(this.id);" href="http://'.$result['WEB'].'" id="'.$result['ID_PAG'].'" target="_blank">'.$result['WEB'].'</a><br />';
```

Javascript (In head section)

```
function sumar(id){($.post("suma.php",{pag:id})}
```

Suma.php

```
$pag=$_POST['pag'];
$mysqli->query("UPDATE lapag SET visitas=visitas+1 WHERE id_pag=".$pag);
```

Thank You!

Comment: I think your way should work well - where is the problem with this solution?

Comment: It doesn't work. Go to the web page, but the sumar.php is not executed :(

Comment: your javasvript function call suma.php and not sumar.php

Comment: Oh! Sorry, that is a mistake at the php file name of the text, but it's right in my real file. Now it is corrected.

Comment: @ekans I belive in the accumulated experience shows that the constant dissemination of information may lead us to consider restructuring the desired rates. Otherwise you can use PDO to do this queries. I prefer use frameworks Like Zend PHP. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the apostrophs right? I c/p html part into eclipse and it did not particularly like it.

```
echo "<br><a onClick='sumar(this.id)'";
echo "href='http://".$result['WEB'] . "'";
echo "id=". $result['ID_PAG'] . 'target="_blank">';
echo $result['WEB']. "</a><br />";
```

I have broken it up into several echoes in order to make it clearer and easier to handle.

Comment: Hi! I think that the quotes are right because, when I watch the code on Firebug, I read

<a target="_blank" id="3" href="http://www.unaweb.es" onclick="sumar(this.id);">www.unaweb.es</a>

Is it normal that "this.id" into the function?Should not be a number or the name of an object?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="sumar.php?web=<?php echo $result['WEB'];?>&id=<?php echo $result['ID_PAG'];?> target="_blank"><?php echo $result['WEB']; ?></a>
```

Sumar.php

```
$pag=$_GET['ID_PAG'];
$mysqli->query("UPDATE lapag SET visitas=visitas+1 WHERE id_pag=".$pag);
header("Location: http://".$_GET['WEB']); // redirect
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you NIsam, that solution works, but I would like to avoid the redirection from the php file. Anyway, I'll use this code if anybody solves my doubt.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Think best practice should look like this:

```
<a href="http://random.org" onclick='called(event, this,  "clicked")'>Visit site</a>
```

```
function called(event, link, id){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var theUrl = "counter.php";
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (this.readyState != 4)       //4 means call is finished - we just want to switch side after the counter-call finished
            return;
        window.location.href = link.href.value;
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.send("id="+id);
    return false;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/porotobuna/1/edit?html,js,output

In the counter.php just get the get variable "id" (which represents the clicked link) and handle the counter (I recommend some kind of database)

Comment: Hi Verim.

I see your code, but I don't know how it works. I would have to ask about GET vars in counter.php, wouldn't I?

Why this.readyState have to be different to 4? Sorry but I'm not used to encode javascript.